# Cypress Tool -- how to do click action on Show and Hide button, unable to do action on this button

Tags: cypress, ui-automation

i have a scenario like below with hide and show button
when i fill some data in input box action witll show me  button  else button is in hide mode
the below is the code , please suggest me solution how to run my automation code after entering code in input box

when button enabled mode -- with out text entering in input box

<button data-v-320fbb42= type="button" disabled="disabled" class="btn z-btn mr-1 btn-primary rounded-0 disabled" style="position: relative;"><div data-v-320fbb42= class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">Save </div></button>

else
when button disabled mode --  after entering proper text in input box

<button data-v-d0c5d35c= type="button" class="btn z-btn mr-1 btn-primary rounded-0" style="position: relative;"><div data-v-d0c5d3c= class=d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center>
Save </div></button>

so i tried all the scenarios like below , but noting is working ,
cy.get('button').should('be.disabled').invoke('show').should('be.enabled').contains('Save').click()

```
 cy.contains('Save').click({force: true})
cy.get('button', 'Save').should('be.disabled');
 cy.contains('button', 'Save').click();
```

Thanks for your suggestion or help

Comment: Would it work, if you check that the class name for disabled button has the word disabled and vice-versa ?

Comment: @AlapanDas Thanks for suggestion it not worked , tried all the scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Since your disable status is based on a class - I have found the next solution for validation in https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Value

```
cy.get('button', 'Save').should('have.class', 'disabled')

cy.input(inputSelector).type(text)
cy.get('button', 'Save').should('not.have.class', 'disabled')
```

And a solution for forcibly enabling it

```
$(selector).removeClass('disabled')
cy.get('button', 'Save').should('not.have.class', 'disabled')
```